# ESP8266 - AP+STA mode not working properly

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to have an ESP8266 ESP-12 to serve as Access Point and Station at the same time, delivering the same webpage in both cases.
This is what I have:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP.h>

const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
DNSServer dnsServer;

MDNSResponder mdns;
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

String ssid = "";
String password = "";
String webPage = "";


void setup(void){

  IPAddress Ip(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress NMask(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(Ip, Ip, NMask);
  WiFi.softAP(conf_ssid.c_str());
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Soft AP Started");
  Serial.println("");

  /* Setup the DNS server redirecting all the domains to the Ip */  
  dnsServer.setErrorReplyCode(DNSReplyCode::NoError);
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "www.example.com", Ip);

  //connectToWifi();
  getCredentials(); //Reads Home WiFi credentials from the EEPROM
  if (ssid != "" and password != ""){
    WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  }
  server.begin();

  // When no password is present
  if ((ssid == "" and password == "") or (ssid == "Error")){
    // ****** MAIN PAGE ******
    server.on("/", [](){ /* HANDLES CREDENTIAL INPUT */   });
    server.begin();
  }
  else // If we have ssid and password -- check if we have connection
  {
    webPage += "<h1>Main Webpage</h1>";
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    server.begin();
    //if (mdns.begin("esp8266", WiFi.localIP())) {
     // Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    //}

    server.on("/", [](){
      server.send(200, "text/html", webPage);
    });
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  }
}

void loop(void){
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Basically, it reads the credentials from the EEPROM, if there is no credential, a WiFi configuration page is displayed, otherwise it also connects to the WiFi serving the Main Webpage to both AP and Station.

The issue is that, even though I can see the AP and a ping from my PC to the WiFi Station's Ip works, I can only access the webpage if I'm connected via AP, not via Station.
Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: how did you find out the IP address of STA?

Comment: would not one server.begin() at the end of setup be enough?

Comment: The STA IP is retrieved via serial console. And having only one server.begin() gives the same result, that was just me trying something different when I tried to reset the esp whenever the configuration changed

Comment: You know https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager  ?

Comment: What is the IP and default gateway of your PC?

Comment: @Juraj I'm gonna check that.

Comment: @Code Gorilla, why do you need that?what are you thinking?

Comment: I was wondering if it could be a simple routing issue rather than actually a problem with you code.  When you connect via the station I guess there is another access point involved and unless you have got the routing write it will do what you describe.  (Yeah I don't actually want you IP and gateways address - well done for not posting them :) )

Comment: @Code Gorilla thanks, I'm not sure that I followed your thought, but I'll try playing around with gateways and stuff and came back with the results

Comment: @CodeGorilla I've been thinking on your solution, but I think that this is not the case, since I can connect through my PC when I don't try to make both connections work at the same time. Any other idea?

Comment: Some additional information: the only goal on this is to be able to know the IP of the ESP so I can find it on the net, if there is any other solution to this, please let me know. Thanks